# C concatenating strings won't work

Tags: c, string, algorithm, concatenation

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char data[1024];
    data[0] = '\0';
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        strcpy(data+strlen(data), (argv[i] + 1));
    }
    strcpy(data+strlen(data), data+strlen(data)/2);
    printf(data);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see this is my code so far. What I'm trying to do is: Remove first letter from every argument, concat them into `data` and after the loop take half of the resulting string and concat it again, then print it. Example:

Calling the program with the arguments `hello`, `world` and `yes` should print:
elloorldesrldes

it works until `strcpy(data+strlen(data), data+strlen(data)/2);`. Here I try to take half of the string (`data`) and concat it to the end of the same string. When I leave that part out I get the result `elloorldes` but when I put it in, instead of giving me the expected results I get the error `RUN FAILED (exit value -1.073.741.819, total time: 4s)`, however I'm not sure why that's the case.

Comment: You are clobbering the null terminator of the string being copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this

```
strcpy(data+strlen(data), data+strlen(data)/2);
```

because `strcpy` cannot handle cases when memory overlaps.

> *man strcpy*
>
> ```
> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The  `strcpy()`  function  copies  the  string pointed to by `src`, including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`),
>   to the buffer pointed to by `dest`. **The strings may not overlap**, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.

You need to use `memmove` for this, which handles memory overlap:

```
size_t oldsize = strlen(data);
size_t size = oldsize/2;

memmove(data+oldsize, data+size, size);
data[oldsize + size] = 0;
```

Also don't do `printf(data)` with content provided by the user. Let's say the
passed arguments are `hello`, `world%d`, then `data` will contain `%d` and
`printf` would yield undefined behaviour, because there are arguments missing.

You should do this:

```
printf("%s\n", data);
```

or

```
puts(data);
```